# Trying to use azcopy for copying file from storage account

Tags: azure, rhel7, azcopy

Uploaded a .sh file into storage account and trying to get that into rhel vm. I have azcopy version 10.6.1. Command i am using azcopy copy ”https://.blob.core.windows.net/container/test.sh>[SAS token]" . When i run this, it is moving to next line and giving this ">" output. Tried to do in many ways but no luck.

How can we troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Hi Aditya c, Hope the below response was helpful. Let me know if you have any further queries regarding it.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to use "azcopy copy" command is

```
azcopy copy [source] [destination] [flags]
```

To download a single file by using a SAS token:

```
azcopy cp "https://[account].blob.core.windows.net/[container]/[path/to/blob]?[SAS]" "/path/to/file.txt"
```

To download a single file by using a SAS token and then piping the output to a file (block blobs only):

```
azcopy cp "https://[account].blob.core.windows.net/[container]/[path/to/blob]?[SAS]" > "/path/to/file.txt"
```

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy) is the source of above information.

Related references:

- [Download blobs from Azure Blob storage by using AzCopy v10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs-download?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json)
- [Troubleshoot Azcopy related issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-configure#troubleshoot-issues)